# Build Web application on two separated frameworks

Tags: laravel, web-applications, vue.js

My team has to develop a project for a large fleet company which will be fleet management system. we will use Laravel framework to build it. My question is "Does it considered a good practice to build the Backend on Laravel by implementing APIs only then to have another framework like Vue.js to Build the Frontend?

Comment: Laravel accepts vuejs in frontend. It has example component in `resources/assets/js/components`. Laravel is perfect for frontend and backend.

Comment: @MRustamzade Can you see any pros and cons from the suggested architecture? Just mention some of, if you have an experience in such solution

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with what you have described. Laravel is a big supporter of the Vue project even to the point Larvel's docs and supporting sites are written in Vue. Since 5.3 Laravel has come with a Vue example built into the starter project. The [Writing Javascript](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend#writing-javascript) section of the docs covers this more in depth.

Comment: @WildBeard What are pros and cons for this approach?

Comment: [Pros and Cons of a Frontend Framework](https://envisionitagency.com/blog/2018/04/pros-cons-front-end-web-frameworks/)

Comment: Have you completed this application in Laravel-Vuejs? What difficulties you faced? I need to start a fleet management on the same tech-stack